# Proactive message using smooch telegram and zendesk

Tags: telegram-bot, zendesk, smooch

I need to contact my userbase using telegram via smooch, the flow is:

- send a message to users with the bot link
- the user clicks the link and accepts to receive messages from the bot
- using smooch webhook, I need to recognize the user on my system so, I need to pass a parameter in the bot link.

Is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE OCT-7: the fix has been introduced! You will now get back the referral code in the `conversation:start` webhook that you specified in the link

example: https://telegram.me/my_amazing_smooch_bot?start=myParameter

This will show up in the property referral.code like in the sample below

UPDATE OCT-4: we will introduce the fix early next week (probably Tuesday Oct 8) and you will have the property `referral` as shown in the webhook below

```
{
    "trigger": "conversation:start",
    "app": {
        "_id": "5d83cd561848924fe36ccb22"
    },
    "version": "v1.1",
    "source": {
        "type": "telegram",
        "integrationId": "5d97392ee784e3586d8f41b8"
    },
    "appUser": {
        "_id": "6c7cf3f8d64c3d996d06c8dd",
        "conversationStarted": true,
        "givenName": "Bobby",
        "signedUpAt": "2019-10-04T16:54:01.550Z",
        "properties": {}
    },
    "timestamp": 1570214057.443,
    "conversation": {
        "_id": "af62c3a0450401ee1bf0f0f1"
    },
    "referral": {
        "code": "myParameter"
    }
}
```

The way you would do this is by specifying the parameter like so :

https://telegram.me/my_amazing_smooch_bot?start=myParameter

Unfortunately, we currently swallow this parameter and the conversation:start webhook we send does not forward the parameter back to you

I will get back to you regarding this 'fix' we needs to make on our end to accommodate this use case

Thank you!

Bobby Connolly
Zendesk Inc.